# get value of selected item in second column... returning previous item

Tags: vb.net

I get that there are other questions like this, but for some reason nobody seems to have this problem.  I'm trying to populate a 2 column listview that I create on load like this.

```
With lstShipMethods
    .View = View.Details
    .FullRowSelect = True
    .HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None ' set to whatever you need
    .Columns.Clear() ' make sure collumnscollection is empty
    ' Add 3 columns
    .Columns.AddRange(New ColumnHeader() {New ColumnHeader(), New ColumnHeader()})
End With

lstShipMethods.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({"col1data", "col2data1"}))
lstShipMethods.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({"col1data", "col2data2"}))
```

It populates just fine, but when I try to get the data from the selected items column like this

```
Private Sub lstShipMethods_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstShipMethods.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim val As String = lstShipMethods.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text
    MessageBox.Show(val)
End Sub
```

after the first click it will always show both values aka second column from row one and row two will be output in the `MessageBox`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ItemSelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged.aspx) event instead.

```
Private Sub lstShipMethods_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles lstShipMethods.ItemSelectionChanged
    If e.IsSelected Then
        Dim val As String = lstShipMethods.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text
        MessageBox.Show(val)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank god... this was driving me freaking nuts